# Accessing array from functional child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, ecmascript-6, react-props

I have built a sortable list using this react library https://github.com/bokuweb/react-sortable-pane

It accepts an array and a function. the checkOrder function fires onDragStop. In this function, I would like to see the order of my array(rankChoiceArray)

```
const RankChoiceQuestions = props => {
  const { rankChoiceArray, checkOrder } = props
  return (
    <ItemContainer>
      <SortablePane direction="vertical" onDragStop={() => checkOrder(rankChoiceArray)}>
        {rankChoiceArray
          .sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5)
          .map(questionChoice => {
            return (
              <Pane
                className="item"
                key={questionChoice.id}
                defaultSize={{ width: 270, height: 60 }}
                resizable={{ x: false, y: false, xy: false }}
              >
                {questionChoice.text}
                {console.log('this', this)}
              </Pane>
            )
          })}
      </SortablePane>
    </ItemContainer>
  )
}
```

The component feeds into another component(sibling?)

```
const Question = props => {
  let rankChoice
  switch (props.data.type) {
    case 'rankChoice':
      rankChoice = (
        <RankChoiceQuestions rankChoiceArray={props.data.choices} checkOrder={props.checkOrder} />
      )
      break

    default:
      responses = <div>Error: no question type: `{props.data.type}`</div>
  }
  const { data } = props
  return (
    <AnimatedDiv key={data.id}>
      <QuestionText>{data.text}</QuestionText>
      {rankChoice}
    </AnimatedDiv>
  )
}
```

Everything then finally is plugged into the Parent class-based component

```
this.state = { order: [] }
<Question
          data={questions.find(q => q.id === currentQuestionId)}
          checkOrder={this.test}
        />
```

How can I get access to the array props?

```
test = () => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      order: state.order,
    }))
    console.log('event fired', this)
  }
```

Comment: You can only send data from a child component to the parent using an even handler. If it is data which is not supposed to be sent via an event handler, then you need to save it in the state in the parent component

Comment: What do I need to change? my test function is firing, I'm just not sure how to access the array

Comment: I'm guessing your test function is in the parent component right? Also how are you calling it?

Comment: Yup, thats correct, It gets called each time I stop dragging the <Pane /> element,

    onDragStop={() => checkOrder(rankChoiceArray)}> is a prop on my child component, parent component then calls it like this checkOrder={this.test}

Comment: You are talking about dragging something, which requires the `onDrag` or the `onDragStop` event handler. Something like <Pane onDragStop={()=>yourFunction(your_data)} />

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding my question, the event handler is already firing my test function. In my test function I would like to see the array

Comment: @invrt, just add a parameter for the array to your test function

Comment: @AlexanderVidaurreArroyo lol thanks, not sure how I missed that. >.>